# tomcat6 windows service properties default memory

Tags: windows-services, tomcat6

Hello I have tomcat6 as a windows server.
I am considering increasing the mmeory but I am not sure how much memory it currently has.
It is run as a service and there is a "Configure Tomcat" icon in the start menu
This has a java-tab with "Initial memory pool" and "Maximum memory pool" both of which are empty. What is the default on these?
There are also some Java Options:

```
 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat6\temp
 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Tomcat6\conf\logging.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Tomcat 6 is configured to use a minimum of 64 MB of RAM and a maximum of 128 MB of RAM allocated to the heap.

I would suggest to increase the max memory pool to at least 1024 MB. This could be increased, depending upon your server needs.

If you want to increase the Permanent Generation memory, you can add this in a separate line in the Java Options text area :
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m